# Is there a way to keep rows with a specific condition, and remove others if this condition is not met?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, duplicates

I have the following dataframe (df)

```
                ID  start                        end                     Diff
                A   1/8/2020 12:00:00 AM         1/8/2020 12:00:10 AM    10
                A   1/8/2020 12:00:05 AM         1/8/2020 12:00:10 AM    5
                B   1/9/2020 1:00:05 AM          1/9/2020 1:00:10 AM     5
                B   1/9/2020 1:00:06 AM          1/9/2020 1:00:10 AM     4
                B   1/9/2020 1:00:20 AM          1/9/2020 1:00:25 AM     5
                C   1/10/2020 5:00:05 AM         1/10/2020 5:00:25 AM    20
                C   1/10/2020 5:00:40 AM         1/10/2020 5:00:45 AM    5
```

Here is the problem:
When the end times are identical, I would like to delete the row with the longer duration, deleting the row with the shortest duration.

Desired outcome:

```
                ID  start                      end                     Diff
                A   1/8/2020 12:00:05 AM       1/8/2020 12:00:10 AM    5
                B   1/9/2020 1:00:06 AM        1/9/2020 1:00:10 AM     4
                B   1/9/2020 1:00:20 AM        1/9/2020 1:00:25 AM     5
                C   1/10/2020 5:00:05 AM       1/10/2020 5:00:25 AM    20
                C   1/10/2020 5:00:40 AM       1/10/2020 5:00:45 AM    5
```

Essentially, when the end time is identical, I wish to remove the row that has the longer duration.
I have tried this, however, it is not taking into account the condition: 
Retain the shorter duration row when the end time is identical

```
                df.sort_values(['Diff']).drop_duplicates(subset=['ID'])
```

Any suggestion(s) is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `groupby` on `end` column transformed with the minimum value of `Diff` , then compare with `df['Diff']` and keep those which return True, check how transform returns the minimum over an entire group below:

```
df[df['Diff'].eq(df.groupby('end')['Diff'].transform('min'))]
```

---

```
  ID                 start                   end  Diff
1  A  1/8/2020 12:00:05 AM  1/8/2020 12:00:10 AM     5
3  B   1/9/2020 1:00:06 AM   1/9/2020 1:00:10 AM     4
4  B   1/9/2020 1:00:20 AM   1/9/2020 1:00:25 AM     5
5  C  1/10/2020 5:00:05 AM  1/10/2020 5:00:25 AM    20
6  C  1/10/2020 5:00:40 AM  1/10/2020 5:00:45 AM     5
```

---

Output of `groupby+transform`

```
print(df.groupby('end')['Diff'].transform('min'))

0     5
1     5
2     4
3     4
4     5
5    20
6     5
```

---

```
print(df['Diff'].eq(df.groupby('end')['Diff'].transform('min')))

0    False
1     True
2    False
3     True
4     True
5     True
6     True
```

Comment: ok I will try. Can you explain what the code is doing? I am still learning more about Pandas

Comment: @TanishaHudson just updated with explanation :) let me know if you need anything

Comment: this worked perfectly. I have to wait 10 minutes to Upvote. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

We could use [`Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html)

```
df[df['Diff'].eq(df['end'].map(df.groupby('end')['Diff'].min()))]

  ID                 start                   end  Diff
1  A  1/8/2020 12:00:05 AM  1/8/2020 12:00:10 AM     5
3  B   1/9/2020 1:00:06 AM   1/9/2020 1:00:10 AM     4
4  B   1/9/2020 1:00:20 AM   1/9/2020 1:00:25 AM     5
5  C  1/10/2020 5:00:05 AM  1/10/2020 5:00:25 AM    20
6  C  1/10/2020 5:00:40 AM  1/10/2020 5:00:45 AM     5
```

Comment: Very helpful too. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Sort by `'start'` and the "shorter" duration will naturally be last.  Then use `drop_duplicates`

```
df.sort_values(['ID', 'start', 'end']).drop_duplicates(['ID', 'end'], keep='last')

  ID               start                 end  Diff
1  A 2020-01-08 00:00:05 2020-01-08 00:00:10     5
3  B 2020-01-09 01:00:06 2020-01-09 01:00:10     4
4  B 2020-01-09 01:00:20 2020-01-09 01:00:25     5
5  C 2020-01-10 05:00:05 2020-01-10 05:00:25    20
6  C 2020-01-10 05:00:40 2020-01-10 05:00:45     5
```

Answer (score 1):

Sort by `ID` and `end`, then take the one with the shortest `Diff`.

```
>>> df.sort_values(['ID', 'end', 'Diff']).groupby(['ID', 'end'], sort=False).head(1)

  ID                 start                   end  Diff
1  A  1/8/2020 12:00:05 AM  1/8/2020 12:00:10 AM     5
3  B   1/9/2020 1:00:06 AM   1/9/2020 1:00:10 AM     4
4  B   1/9/2020 1:00:20 AM   1/9/2020 1:00:25 AM     5
5  C  1/10/2020 5:00:05 AM  1/10/2020 5:00:25 AM    20
6  C  1/10/2020 5:00:40 AM  1/10/2020 5:00:45 AM     5
```